# Submit to Play Store, Android app supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have tried 7 topics with issues same this: Android app is supported by 0 devices.

When installing from APK files, all of my device work well, cannot understand about this issue.

Can anyone help me to know how to fix my manifest file?
Here is permission: (I had tried to add some "uses-feature" but still the same issue).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.amel.apps">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amel.apps"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `App Releases` section of Play Store?

Comment: Yes, It's App Release, it's available in PlayStore but no one can install it.

Comment: Is your application live? Have you rolled out the production?

Comment: I have rolled out the production already, the status is "Published". But still not be searched on store.

Comment: Is your app searchable on PlayStore is a different issue. After clicking on `View in Play Store` can you install it?

Comment: My app is not searchable on PlayStore. After click on View in Play Store I can't install it. The message is: "This app is incompatible with all of your devices"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156463/discussion-between-novo-lucas-and-khiem-trung).

Comment: Are you include this line in gradle dependencies
`compile  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` ?

Comment: if you are using jar libs, if possible to replace with gradle dependencies replace it.

Comment: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` was already in my dependencies